# How can I codify Cloudwatch alarms used by Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been codifying some AWS infrastructure with Terraform. We have a web application deployed to Elastic Beanstalk, and I've been trying to add [aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_metric_alarm.html)s to it.

I can do this fine - by setting the AutoScalingGroupName dimension to that of the Beanstalk environment, it correctly configures the alarm and I can see that alarm within the AWS Console by navigating to Cloudwatch. However, it's absent from the list of alarms if I try to navigate through the Elastic Beanstalk configuration.

[image: eb-alarms]

As you can see in this screenshot, Elastic Beanstalk has its own tab called "Alarms." Suffice it to say that when I create alarms here, through the console, they show up in two places: here (under Elastic Beanstalk) as well as through the Cloudwatch > Alarms view in the console.

When I create alarms through Terraform, they show up in the latter location, but not under the Elastic Beanstalk configuration. As far as I can tell, everything about the Cloudwatch alarms themselves is identical. Yet there seems to be some hidden property that associates the alarms with the EB environment that I can't put my finger on. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that Cloudwatch metrics are [Name spaced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/aeb-metricscollected.html) and Elastic beanstalk is only pulling the metrics for EB, and the ones you are creating are not in the Elastic beanstalk namespace.

You can add Cloudwatch monitors after the fact to the console board by following the directions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-health-console.html) but I do not see how to do it in Terraform.

[image]

> To add an overview or graph
>
> 1. Click Edit in the Overview or Monitoring section.
> 2. Select a Resource. The supported resources are your environment's
>      Auto Scaling group, Elastic Load Balancing load balancer, and the
>      environment itself.
> 3. Select a CloudWatch metric for the resource. See Publishing Amazon
>      CloudWatch Custom Metrics for an Environment for a full list of
>      supported metrics.
> 4. Select a Statistic. The default statistic is the average value of
>      the selected cloudwatch metric during the time range (overview) or
>      between plot points (graph).
> 5. Enter a Description. The description is the label for the item shown
>      in the monitoring console.
> 6. Click Add.
>
> Repeat the previous steps to add more items or click Save to finish modifying the panel.

Comment: I don't think the Cloudwatch alarms are namespaced as you suggested simply because the CPUUtilization metric is not listed in the table you linked to yet that is one of the metrics I was able to set up through the EB Alarm Console.

Comment: I can confirm that (as of Jan 2019) adding the "AWS/ElasticBeanstalk" namespace doesn't change anything. The alarm is still missing from the Beanstalk UI, but correctly created and visible thru CloudWatch